# Cache built dynamically?

Tags: cache, reindex

Magento 1.9.  Are the caches built by Refresh or built dynamically when user accesses?

My experience is, after caches refreshed, first time user accesses link it's slow but all subsequent times it's fast.

Also, all my Indexes are "Update on Save" mode, Status = Ready and Update Required = No.  Can I trust those green bars or should I manually Reindex?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the cache is built on first page load. If loading for the first time is slow, then it's usually caused by a code issue in the page. (Try debugging on a staging/dev instance with the cache set to "off")

"Update on save" means that the index is partially rebuilt when the product is saved. Again, this can be slow if you have several staff editing products at once, a solution to that would be a "Async re-index" plugin.